# Automatic prioritization with form using php

Tags: php, html, forms

Ok so I have basic question and I was not really sure where to being and I was hoping someone could could point in the right direction for research.

I am making a form where customers can fill out a ticket request. The ticket then gets put to our ticket system. When it is there I want them to be sorted by priority.
I plan on asking questions like Are you able to log in? Yes or No. Yes gets 0 points and No gets 1. The people with the highest number go to the top of the line.

I also want to be able to pull out buzz words from the text.

My questions are is this possible? Do I seem to have the right idea with it? Is there a better way to do this? Any suggested articles to read?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's a great idea, and it can work. Use php with mysql commands to count the number of one's and zero's. When done, have the mysql command sort your counts by whichever is highest, and echo the array via php.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the rating system, you could do some math.

Set the value of Yes to "0" and No to "1", and when the form submits calculate a total of all the values, store it in a separate column in the database and then when you're printing out all the tickets you can sort it to show the tickets with the highest values at the top.